# How to fix Amazon RDS database that is in anInsufficient-resource-limits

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am having some issue with our AWS Aurora PostgreSQL RDS DB. DB instance status is in Insufficient-resource-limits state.

Screenshot of the console:

[image]

The error in the CI to the RDS update:

```
 Error: waiting for RDS Cluster  create: unexpected state 'insufficient-resource-limits', wanted target 'available'. last error: %!s(<nil>)
```

I don't have enough info to debug, I checked all my service quota & nothing seems  exceed the limits

Comment: Why not enough info? Have you checked the `Logs & events`?

Comment: @Riz actually there is no **logs & event** & also, i cannot delete or backup the rds...

Comment: Can you see the metrics in cloudwatch or rds monitoring? Do you see anything strange there? Is this a new db or it was working and suddenly this issue happend? Also, can you modify it? If yes, maybe change the instance type and more space and check. Can't seem to find anything related to this error. OR open a support ticket if you can.

Comment: I see no logs in cloudwatch, I'm opening case to AWS, thank you for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a case to AWS Support, & it was the number of Custom endpoint per Cluster.

"An Aurora DB cluster has no custom endpoints until you create one. You can create up to five custom endpoints for each provisioned Aurora cluster."

Source : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html